# Why does the "devices" tag exist?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What benefit does the [devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devices) tag provide? It seems really vague and unnecessary in almost every possible circumstance. The only question that seems to even remotely use it in a reasonable manner is https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11548/list-of-gpl-compliant-android-devices, but I'd argue that could be closed as "Not Constructive" or "Too Localized" anyway.

Am I missing a use-case here, or does this tag deserve to be burninated?

Comment: This brought to my attention a whole ton of other terrible tags as well, so thanks :)

Comment: @MatthewRead: Ha, sure thing. Guess they travel in packs, eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it partially served as a list of questions that needed to be closed / deleted :P

I've removed it from all questions and it should disappear soon.